# How to Store & Retrieve Image from MYSQL Online Database Android without php

Tags: java, android, mysql, database

I tried following code in android studio onactivity result to get image and convert into inputstream and other formats but it is not storing and retrieving image from database. Please check. & it is in android

```
if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

            Uri uri = data.getData();

            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
                iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
                byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
                inputStream=new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
}
```

Comment: ideally you don't want to hardcode your MySQL username password in a (Client) Java application because if can be decompiled then somebody has full access with that username and password on MySQL.